# MVC5: serve dynamically generated .less from actionresult

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5, less

I'm trying to create an mvc action which can accept as parameter the extension of a file, in particular for .less and .css file.

I'd like to call an action "Palette" of a controller "ColorController" mapped to the route

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ColorPalette",
                url: "{controller}/{action}.{ext}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Color", action = "Palette", ext = "less" }
            );
```

where `{ext}` is the extension (less or css).

The colors are stored on the database and I want to import my "dynamic less" in the main less file of the website.

I've tried a lot of times, adding handlers

```
<add name="ColorPalette" path="palette/colors.less" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

in the web config and trying different types of routing, but the application always give me a 404 or 500 error.

If I call the "standard" url everything works as expected.

Any suggestion?
Thank you